# Express passing arrays into sql (express/mssql/react)

Tags: javascript, sql, express

I am trying to upload two arrays into my sql database. 
This is what I have come up with.(this is my server.js using a endpoint from my client side)

My express

```
app.post("/post-question-answers", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("!called");
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    let results = req.body.results;

    let questions = [];
    let answers = [];

    results.forEach(element => questions.push(element.question));
    results.forEach(element => answers.push(element.answer));

    for (var i = -1; i < results.length; i++) {
      request.input("Question", sql.VarChar, questions[i]);
      request.input("Answer", sql.VarChar, answers[i]);
      request.execute("dbo.AddQuestionResponses", function(err, recordset) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // send records as a response
        res.json(recordset);
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

My sql stored procedrue

```
alter procedure AddQuestionResponses
@Question nvarchar (50),
@Answer nvarchar (50)


as 

insert into QuestionResponses(QuestionWhenAnswered, QuestionResponse)
values (@Question ,@Answer )
```

However this throws

```
RequestError: The parameter name Question has already been declared. Parameter names must be unique
```

I believe this is because

```
  request.input("Question", sql.VarChar, questions[i]);
      request.input("Answer", sql.VarChar, answers[i]);
```

need to be unique and as they are in a for loop they are repeated within the statement. Is there a way in which I can make this a valid transaction with the database and so that these are unique.

Thankyou for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by putting

```
var request = new sql.Request();
```

within the for loop.